# Programmatically open nested, collapsed (hidden) nodes in d3.js v6

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, promise, callback

A follow-on question / issue to

[Programmatically open nested, collapsed (hidden) node in d3.js v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67527258/programmatically-open-nested-collapsed-hidden-node-in-d3-js-v4)

updated for d3.js v6.  The issue is the loading of external JSON data in the d3 collapsible menu visualization, and the programmatic access of nested (collapsed, hidden) nodes.

It appears that "treeData", which is the loaded Object, is not being delivered.

```js
Uncaught ReferenceError: treeData is not defined
```

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/vstuart/kant09hm/6/

**JSFiddle (updated with answer):** https://jsfiddle.net/vstuart/kant09hm/9/

---

**ontology_for_d3_test.json**

- gist: https://gist.github.com/victoriastuart/abbcf355bf1590be02f6dec297be2706

```js
{ "name": "Root",
  "children": [
    { "name": "Culture",
      "children": [
        { "name": "Entertainment" },
        { "name": "LGBT" }
      ]
    },

    { "name": "Nature",
      "id": "nature",
      "children": [
        { "name": "Earth",
          "id": "earth",
          "children": [
            { "name": "Environment" },
            { "name": "Geography" },
            { "name": "Geology" },
            { "name": "Geopolitical" },
            { "name": "Geopolitical - Countries" },
            { "name": "Geopolitical - Countries - Canada" },
            { "name": "Geopolitical - Countries - United States" },
            { "name": "Nature" },
            { "name": "Regions" }
          ]
        },
        { "name": "Cosmos" },
        { "name": "Outer space" }
      ]
    },

    { "name": "Humanities",
      "children": [
          { "name": "History" },
          { "name": "Philosophy" },
          { "name": "Philosophy - Theology" }
      ]
    },

    { "name": "Miscellaneous",
      "children": [
          { "name": "Wikipedia",
            "url": "https://wikipedia.com" },
          { "name": "Example.com",
            "url": "https://example.com" }
      ]
    },
      
    { "name": "Science",
      "children": [
          { "name": "Biology" },
          { "name": "Health" },
          { "name": "Health - Medicine" },
          { "name": "Sociology" }
      ]
    },

    { "name": "Technology",
      "children": [
            { "name": "Computers" },
            { "name": "Computers - Hardware" },
            { "name": "Computers - Software" },
            { "name": "Computing" },
            { "name": "Computing - Programming" },
            { "name": "Internet" },
            { "name": "Space" },
          { "name": "Transportation" }
      ]
    },

  { "name": "Society",
      "children": [
            { "name": "Business" },
            { "name": "Economics" },
            { "name": "Economics - Business" },
            { "name": "Economics - Capitalism" },
            { "name": "Economics - Commerce" },
            { "name": "Economics - Finance" },
            { "name": "Politics" },
          { "name": "Public services" }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

---

**index.html** [standalone working copy of JSFiddle; edit: updated with answer]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

<head>
  <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">

  <style>
    .node {
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .node circle {
      fill: #fff;
      stroke: steelblue;
      stroke-width: 3px;
    }

    .node text {
      font: 12px sans-serif;
    }

    .link {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #ccc;
      stroke-width: 2px;
    }

    #includedContent {
      position: static !important;
      display: inline-block;
    }

    #d3_object {
      width: 75%;
      margin: 0.5rem 0.5rem 1rem 0.25rem;
    }
  </style>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!-- <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script> -->
  <!-- <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script> -->
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="d3_object">
    <object>
      <p>apple</p>
      <div id="includedContent"></div>
      <p>banana</p>
    </object>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    // Set the dimensions and margins of the diagram
    var margin = {top: 20, right: 90, bottom: 30, left: 90},
        width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    // ----------------------------------------
    // PAN, ZOOM:

    // https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/interactivity_zoom.html
    // var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")

    var svg = d3.select("#includedContent").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        // d3.js v4, v5:
        // .call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", function () {
        //   svg.attr("transform", d3.event.transform)
        // d3.js v6:
        .call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", function (event) {
          svg.attr("transform", event.transform)
        }))
      .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate("
              + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
    // ----------------------------------------

    var i = 0,
        duration = 250,
        root;

    // declares a tree layout and assigns the size
    var treemap = d3.tree().size([height, width]);

    // ----------------------------------------
    // LOAD THE EXTERNAL DATA:
    //d3.json("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mbostock/4339083/raw/9585d220bef18a0925922f4d384265ef767566f5/flare.json", function(error, treeData) {

    // ----------------------------------------
    // d3.js v4 [ https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js ]
    /*
      d3.json("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/victoriastuart/abbcf355bf1590be02f6dec297be2706/raw/2418e5f6b7626b3c5842665a51b7d0d27f74e909/ontology_for_d3_test.json", function(error, treeData) {
        if (error) throw error;
        // Assigns parent, children, height, depth
        root = d3.hierarchy(treeData, function(d) { return d.children; });
        root.x0 = height / 2;
        root.y0 = 0;
        // Collapse after the second level
        root.children.forEach(collapse);
        update(root);
      });
    */
    // ----------------------------------------

    // ----------------------------------------
    // d3.js v5   https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js
    //            https://gist.github.com/d3noob/1a96af738c89b88723eb63456beb6510 
    // d3.js v6   https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js
    //            https://gist.github.com/d3noob/9de0768412ac2ce5dbec430bb1370efe

    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49768165/code-within-d3-json-callback-is-not-executed
    // https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/d3js/loading-data-from-file-in-d3js
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47664292/d3-json-method-doesnt-return-my-data-array

    // ----------------------------------------
    // LOAD EXTERNAL JSON DATA FILE (via PROMISE):

    //   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49768165/code-within-d3-json-callback-is-not-executed
    //   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49534470/d3-js-v5-promise-all-replaced-d3-queue
    //   https://www.roelpeters.be/explaining-promises-in-d3-js-the-what-and-the-why/
    //
    //   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

    // This callback function should return the "treeData" Object:
    d3.json("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/victoriastuart/abbcf355bf1590be02f6dec297be2706/raw/2418e5f6b7626b3c5842665a51b7d0d27f74e909/ontology_for_d3_test.json")
      .then(function(treeData) { 
        console.log('[d3.js] treeData:', treeData, '| type:', typeof(treeData), '| length:', treeData['children'].length)
        for (let i = 0; i < treeData['children'].length; i++) {
          console.log('node:', treeData['children'][i].name);
          if ( treeData['children'][i].id !== undefined ) {
            console.log('  id:', treeData['children'][i].id);
          }
        }

        // ASSIGN PARENT, CHILDREN, HEIGHT, DEPTH:
        root = d3.hierarchy(treeData, function(d) { return d.children; });
        root.x0 = height / 2;
        root.y0 = 0;

        // COLLAPSE AFTER THE SECOND LEVEL:
        root.children.forEach(collapse);

        update(root);

        // ----------------------------------------
        // Per answers at
        //   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67527258/programmatically-open-nested-collapsed-hidden-node-in-d3-js-v4/67530786?noredirect=1#comment119390942_67530786
        //   https://jsfiddle.net/mrovinsky/ujwsd7qz/
        //   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67549992/accessing-promised-data-in-d3-js-v6-programmatically-opening-nested-collapsed-n

        const findNodeAncestors = (root, name) => {
          if (root.name === name) {
            return [name];
          }
          if (root.children)
            for (let i = 0; i < root.children.length; i++) {
              const chain = findNodeAncestors(root.children[i], name);
              if (chain) {
                chain.push(root.name);
                return chain;
              }
            }
          return null;
        }; 

        const chain = findNodeAncestors(treeData, 'Earth');

        if (chain) {
          console.log('[d3.js] chain:', chain)

          for (let i = chain.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            const node = d3.select(`.node[node-name="${chain[i]}"]`);
            const nodeData = node.datum();
            if (!nodeData.children && nodeData.data.children) {
              node.node().dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));
            }
          }
        }
        else {
          console.log('[d3.js] "chain" is either "null" or "undefined"')
        }
        // ----------------------------------------

      })
      // IF (ERROR) THROW ERROR:
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log('[d3.js] JSON callback function error')
        if (error) throw error;
      });
    // ----------------------------------------


    // COLLAPSE THE NODE AND ALL IT'S CHILDREN:
    function collapse(d) {
      if(d.children) {
        d._children = d.children
        d._children.forEach(collapse)
        d.children = null
      }
    }

    function update(source) {

      // ASSIGNS THE X AND Y POSITION FOR THE NODES:
      var treeData = treemap(root);

      // COMPUTE THE NEW TREE LAYOUT:
      var nodes = treeData.descendants(),
          links = treeData.descendants().slice(1);

      // NORMALIZE FOR FIXED-DEPTH:
      nodes.forEach(function(d){ d.y = d.depth * 180});

      // *************** NODES SECTION ***************

      // Update the nodes...
      var node = svg.selectAll('g.node')
          .data(nodes, function(d) {return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

      // ENTER ANY NEW MODES AT THE PARENT'S PREVIOUS POSITION:
      var nodeEnter = node.enter().append('g')
          .attr('class', 'node')
          // --------------------------------------------
          // Per answer at
                  //   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67480339/programmatically-opening-d3-js-v4-collapsible-tree-nodes
          .attr('node-name', d => d.data.name)
                  // --------------------------------------------
          .attr("transform", function(d) {
            return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";
        })
        .on('click', click);

      // ADD CIRCLE FOR THE NODES:
      nodeEnter.append('circle')
          .attr('class', 'node')
          .attr('r', 1e-6)
          .style("fill", function(d) {
              return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
          });

      // ADD LABELS FOR THE NODES:
      nodeEnter.append('text')
          .attr("dy", ".35em")
          .attr("x", function(d) {
              return d.children || d._children ? -13 : 13;
          })
          .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
              return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start";
          })
          .text(function(d) { return d.data.name; });

      // UPDATE:
      var nodeUpdate = nodeEnter.merge(node);

      // TRANSITION TO THE PROPER POSITION FOR THE NODE:
      nodeUpdate.transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("transform", function(d) { 
            return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
        });

      // UPDATE THE NODE ATTRIBUTES AND STYLE:
      nodeUpdate.select('circle.node')
        .attr('r', 10)
        .style("fill", function(d) {
            return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
        })
        .attr('cursor', 'pointer');


      // Remove any exiting nodes
      var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
          .duration(duration)
          .attr("transform", function(d) {
              return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")";
          })
          .remove();

      // ON EXIT REDUCE THE NODE CIRCLES SIZE TO 0:
      nodeExit.select('circle')
        .attr('r', 1e-6);

      // ON EXIT REDUCE THE OPACITY OF TEXT LABELS:
      nodeExit.select('text')
        .style('fill-opacity', 1e-6);

      // *************** LINKS SECTION ***************

      // UPDATE THE LINKS:
      var link = svg.selectAll('path.link')
          .data(links, function(d) { return d.id; });

      // ENTER ANY NEW LINKS AT THE PARENT'S PREVIOUS POSITION:
      var linkEnter = link.enter().insert('path', "g")
          .attr("class", "link")
          .attr('d', function(d){
            var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0}
            return diagonal(o, o)
          });

      // UPDATE:
      var linkUpdate = linkEnter.merge(link);

      // TRANSITION BACK TO THE PARENT ELEMENT POSITION:
      linkUpdate.transition()
          .duration(duration)
          .attr('d', function(d){ return diagonal(d, d.parent) });

      // REMOVE ANY EXITING LINKS:
      var linkExit = link.exit().transition()
          .duration(duration)
          .attr('d', function(d) {
            var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y}
            return diagonal(o, o)
          })
          .remove();

      // STORE THE OLD POSITIONS FOR TRANSITION:
      nodes.forEach(function(d){
        d.x0 = d.x;
        d.y0 = d.y;
      });

      // CREATE A CURVED (DIAGONAL) PATH FROM PARENT TO THE CHILD NODES:
      function diagonal(s, d) {

        path = `M ${s.y} ${s.x}
                C ${(s.y + d.y) / 2} ${s.x},
                  ${(s.y + d.y) / 2} ${d.x},
                  ${d.y} ${d.x}`

        return path
      }

      // ----------------------------------------
      // TOGGLE CHILDREN ON CLICK:

      // function click(d) {
      // ***** New in d3.js v6: *****
      function click(event, d) {
        if (d.children) {
          d._children = d.children;
          d.children = null;
        } else if (d._children) {
          d.children = d._children;
          d._children = null;
        } else {
          // This was a leaf node, so redirect.
          console.log('d:', d)
          console.log('d.data:', d.data)
          console.log('d.name:', d.name)
          console.log('d.data.name:', d.data.name)
          console.log('urlMap[d.data.name]:', urlMap[d.data.name])
          window.location = d.data.url;
          // window.open("https://www.example.com", "_self");
        }
        update(d);
      }
      // ----------------------------------------
    }

    // ----------------------------------------
    // Per answer at
    //   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67480339/programmatically-opening-d3-js-v4-collapsible-tree-nodes
    ///*
      setTimeout(() => {
        //const node = d3.select('.node[node-name="Earth"]').node();
        //const node = d3.select('.node[node-name="Nature"]').node();
        const node = d3.select('.node[node-name="Society"]').node();
        console.log('[setTimeout()] NODE: ', node);
        node.dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));
      }, 2500);
    //*/
    // ----------------------------------------

    // ----------------------------------------
    // Per answer at
    //   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67527258/programmatically-open-nested-collapsed-hidden-node-in-d3-js-v4/67530786?noredirect=1#comment119390942_67530786
    //   https://jsfiddle.net/mrovinsky/ujwsd7qz/

    const findNodeAncestors = (root, name) => {
      if (root.name === name) {
        return [name];
      }
      if (root.children)
        for (let i = 0; i < root.children.length; i++) {
          const chain = findNodeAncestors(root.children[i], name);
          if (chain) {
            chain.push(root.name);
            return chain;
          }
        }
      return null;
    }; 

    const chain = findNodeAncestors(treeData, 'Earth');
    // Console: "Uncaught ReferenceError: treeData is not defined"
    
    for (let i = chain.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      const node = d3.select(`.node[node-name="${chain[i]}"]`);
      const nodeData = node.datum();
      if (!nodeData.children && nodeData.data.children) {
        node.node().dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));
      }
    }
    // ----------------------------------------

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `treeData` variable can be used only in the scope of the function where it's defined as an argument:

```
d3.json("https://...json")
  .then(function(treeData) {
    // Scope of the function, treeData can be used here
  });  

// Out of scope, treeData is not defined
```

The solution is to move the block that starts with `const findNodeAncestors...` (~25 lines) inside the function body (right after the last occurence of `update` with a closing brace):

```
        update(d);
      }
      // ----------------------------------------
      // HERE
    }
```